# How to import trace file to OMNeT++/Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

First of all, sorry my bad English...

I have a trace that I exported from SUMO in the format recognized by OMNeT++. Now I need to use it to run some simulations in Veins, **but I don't know how to read/import a trace file in OMNeT++**.

Other information, for these simulations, I do not want to use Veins directly connected to SUMO through the SUMO Proxy, **I would like to use directly the trace that I have**. It is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veins was designed to create a wireless network simulation which interacts with a (running) road traffic simulation, so that both simulations can influence each other. As of Veins 5.1 none of its components can read a mobility trace file.

Other OMNeT++ simulation model libraries can do this. For example, The INET Framework has a number of models that can read mobility traces as well as a model (`ScenarioManager`) which can read node creation/deletion events (which you might need if cars appear/disappear in your simulation). I do not know if/how any of the file formats INET models expect are supported by the SUMO trace writer (which claims that its output can be read by "OMNeT++" without saying which of its many, many models)

Comment: Ok. Thank you, Professor Sommer.